# How to use grep for finding file location in linux machines?

Tags: files, search

How can search for a file in ubuntu os with grep command ?

Let's say, I want to find CMakeList.txt, how to write grep command to find the existence of this file ?

Comment: You mean to say you want to recursively search down directories for this file?

Comment: find command exist for such purpose

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is not the right tool meant for this, use `find` with `-name` to specify the file name you want to get,

```
find . -type f -name "CMakeList.txt" -print
```

The above command searches for the file recursively from the current folder and all the sub-directories below.

Answer (score 0):

If this is on a standard Linux installation, you might also try

```
locate CMakeFile.txt
```

If it is correctly installed, `locate` uses a cached index and is often much faster than a `find` from root directory.

Answer (score -1):

Go into root directory, or a folder that you know your file is in, then

```
dir "CMakeFile.txt"
```

Will find it and its location. Works for me, at least.